# PuppeteerSharp.EvaluationFailedException: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

Using PuppeteerSharp 3.0.0 and .net core 5.0.

The following code throws exception while ran from c#. And running the same script in browser console works just fine. What are we doing wrong?
That's the page: https://www.zillow.com/captchaPerimeterX/?url=%2fhomes%2f&uuid=12d145a0-9798-11eb-b86e-b333bf5d74a4&vid=9508e9f9-9780-11eb-a149-0242ac120003

Code:

```
await page.ReloadAsync();
await page.WaitForNavigationAsync();
var js="document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value=\"03AGdBq27UIr9zjY3QIrVGGmjNSFgFOaRzK04ndNPpdX-PYgKLSQLxyirVwLFnwe7ANCZ-87qzf3dSZiXXWdH6oa80DlySrjhB9RZ9D4u2omiRxub2lMYzf0-yJtE77fqOfhokEknzXfliDaY7Nk44_9G8f_WwIMADykRL1vE39WinWKW3kkwGdRn0UuPicO0aDZqiUStHG_FawNwSLKcpd3ImaJPTWuapyaNq3jGvf96AGQs_DmwkVVjX-IiZHCtlAjhDarppDDw0n3FZEzz0Bef8uVYQXZ0i8zeYy8ScK986nlkF4sbNfuPeJ5JTtAwUfnx1Kacv1RVbod1jSVtzvKoMHH0sgK7Jx6ICQ49oi_wym8e5O7-LZGs-pLgDhdH3ia06rDycMYrMwSOViBFdhtpL7-jLC9px1lFFwezGq7lbxSOp4vkojPhfvRhtUMAdqp6MVa5w8G6t3cQ-ti1n3FVvO2WDMX1h7YhNKsZfvhhFkwNNDALcABauClmGVKLmjOreaSiCnNxSSqLTvyJpneLd9dA2F_22Ag\"";
var elem = await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync(js);
```

Exception:

```
 PuppeteerSharp.EvaluationFailedException: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation. ---> PuppeteerSharp.MessageException: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation. at PuppeteerSharp.CDPSession.SendAsync(String method, Object args, Boolean waitForCallback) in C:\projects\puppeteer-sharp\lib\PuppeteerSharp\CDPSession.cs:line 157 at PuppeteerSharp.CDPSession.SendAsync[T](String method, Object args) in C:\projects\puppeteer-sharp\lib\PuppeteerSharp\CDPSession.cs:line 109 at PuppeteerSharp.ExecutionContext.ExecuteEvaluationAsync(String method, Object args) in C:\projects\puppeteer-sharp\lib\PuppeteerSharp\ExecutionContext.cs:line 182 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: You code worked for me without the `await page.WaitForNavigationAsync()`

Comment: Just tried again, https://www.screencast.com/t/lL6FOOAe
try
            {
                var elem = await WebPage.EvaluateExpressionAsync(js);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
                return false;
            }